# count ids inside the grouped tables

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with counting the ids that are inside the grouped query.  The problem is that this query is grouped according to another variable. For example I need to count how many products are ordered inside the invoice, while this invoice is inside the company that made multiple number of the invoices. I hope it was clear; anyway I hope everything will be more clear with this SQL:

```
SELECT C.FULLNAME,C.COMPANY_ID,SUM(I.GROSSTOTAL) AS TOTAL,
       SUM(I.OTHER_MONEY_VALUE/1.18) AS OTHER_TOTAL,
       COUNT(IR.PRODUCT_ID) AS NO_PRODUCTS
FROM COMPANY C
JOIN #DSN2_ALIAS#.INVOICE I      ON C.COMPANY_ID=I.COMPANY_ID
JOIN #DSN2_ALIAS#.INVOICE_ROW IR ON I.INVOICE_ID=IR.INVOICE_ID
JOIN #DSN3_ALIAS#.PRODUCT P      ON P.PRODUCT_ID=IR.PRODUCT_ID
JOIN #DSN3_ALIAS#.PRODUCT_CAT PC ON P.PRODUCT_CATID=PC.PRODUCT_CATID
WHERE P.PRODUCT_ID=<cfqueryparam value="#attributes.product_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
GROUP BY C.COMPANY_ID,C.FULLNAME
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```

After I define the product id, the query lists in the output the list of companies, with its total sum of sales, and the NO_PRODUCTS has the same value as the number of invoices, because query is grouped by company_id and fullname of it, but the inside each invoice there are multiple number of the products, thus the variable no_products is defined wrongly :(

How can I get the counts correct?

Comment: you tried to use inner query?

Comment: @Ofer no, i dont know how to use it :) i think it must solve the case ))

Comment: @Jack i think it wont change anything :)

Comment: @venom we all think, have you actually tried it? `COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID) AS NO_PRODUCTS`

Comment: At the moment, your description is not clear.  The query as a whole lists the total volumes for each company, accumulating over all the invoices for the company.  Now you say you want to know how many different products were listed in each invoice.  If that's correct, then you need to identify each invoice in the select-list, and add that to the GROUP BY, and then do the COUNT or (perhaps) COUNT(DISTINCT IR.PRODUCT_ID).  But it is a quite radically different query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope i understood what you are trying to do, sorry if i didn't

```
SELECT FULLNAME,COMPANY_ID
FROM (
SELECT SUM(I.GROSSTOTAL) AS TOTAL,
   SUM(I.OTHER_MONEY_VALUE/1.18) AS OTHER_TOTAL,
   COUNT(IR.PRODUCT_ID) AS NO_PRODUCTS
FROM COMPANY C
JOIN #DSN2_ALIAS#.INVOICE I      ON C.COMPANY_ID=I.COMPANY_ID
JOIN #DSN2_ALIAS#.INVOICE_ROW IR ON I.INVOICE_ID=IR.INVOICE_ID
JOIN #DSN3_ALIAS#.PRODUCT P      ON P.PRODUCT_ID=IR.PRODUCT_ID
JOIN #DSN3_ALIAS#.PRODUCT_CAT PC ON P.PRODUCT_CATID=PC.PRODUCT_CATID
WHERE P.PRODUCT_ID=<cfqueryparam value="#attributes.product_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC )
GROUP BY COMPANY_ID,FULLNAME
```

Comment: but as u can see later i need to join on this product_id, while the product_ids are counted and named as no_products :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try to perform an inner query. To retrieve your product count with your invoices. Something similar to this.

```
SELECT C.FULLNAME,C.COMPANY_ID,SUM(I.GROSSTOTAL) AS TOTAL,
       SUM(I.OTHER_MONEY_VALUE/1.18) AS OTHER_TOTAL,NO_PRODUCTS
    FROM COMPANY C
    JOIN #DSN2_ALIAS#.INVOICE I ON C.COMPANY_ID=I.COMPANY_ID
    JOIN (select INVOICE_ID,count(PRODUCT_ID) as NO_PRODUCT from #DSN2_ALIAS#.INVOICE_ROW group by invoice_id) IR ON I.INVOICE_ID=IR.INVOICE_ID
    JOIN #DSN3_ALIAS#.PRODUCT P ON P.PRODUCT_ID=IR.PRODUCT_ID
    JOIN #DSN3_ALIAS#.PRODUCT_CAT PC ON P.PRODUCT_CATID=PC.PRODUCT_CATID
    WHERE 
    P.PRODUCT_ID=<cfqueryparam value="#attributes.product_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
    GROUP BY C.COMPANY_ID,C.FULLNAME
    ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```